# Calling Multiple functions from same controller in magenti2

Tags: magento2

I need to create multiple ajax function in same controller , here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace test\module\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $curl;
    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Curl $curl,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
    {
        $this->curl = $curl;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

   

    public function execute()
    {
        
        $numone = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numone');
        $numtwo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numtwo');
     $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        // $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
        //         ->createBlock('Rgfinmob\Orange\Block\Index')
        //         ->setTemplate('Rgfinmob_Orange::result.phtml')
        //         ->setData('numone',$numone)
        //         ->setData('numtwo',$numtwo)
        //         ->toHtml();
        
                $URL = 'apiurl';
               
               
                //set curl options
               // $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                //set curl header
                $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //get request with url
                $this->curl->get($URL);
                //read response
                $response = $this->curl->getBody();
                $resp= json_decode($response, TRUE);
                $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Rgfinmob\Orange\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('Rgfinmob_Orange::result.phtml')
                ->setData('numone',$resp['make_list'])
                ->toHtml();

                 $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
               // return $response;
      //  $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
       return $result;
    }
    
    public function getVarient()
    {

        
        $brand = $this->getRequest()->getParam('brand');
        //$numtwo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('numtwo');
     $result1 = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
         $resultPage1 = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        // $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
        //         ->createBlock('Rgfinmob\Orange\Block\Index')
        //         ->setTemplate('Rgfinmob_Orange::result.phtml')
        //         ->setData('numone',$numone)
        //         ->setData('numtwo',$numtwo)
        //         ->toHtml();
        
                $URL = 'apiurl';
               
               
                //set curl options
               // $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $this->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                //set curl header
                $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //get request with url
                $this->curl->get($URL);
                //read response
                $response = $this->curl->getBody();
                $resp= json_decode($response, TRUE);
                $block = $resultPage1->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Rgfinmob\Orange\Block\Index\model')
                ->setTemplate('Rgfinmob_Orange::result1.phtml')
                ->setData('model',$resp['model_list'])
                ->toHtml();

                 $result1->setData(['output' => $block]);
               // return $response;
      //  $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
       return $result;
    } 
}
```

here is my part of script

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".result").hide();
    
           

            var url = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'test/result/result/' ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
           
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                
               // console.log(response['success']['make_list']);
                jQuery(".result").show();
                jQuery(".result").html(response.output);
            }
        });
        return false;
        });


    jQuery(document).on('change', '.select_brand', function() {
 
 
  var val=jQuery(this).val();
  var url = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'test/result/result/getVarient/' ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {val:val},
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                
               // console.log(response['success']['make_list']);
                jQuery(".result1").show();
                jQuery(".result1").html(response.output);
            }
        });
        return false;
});

    
});
</script>
```

But both script calling same function , first script should call excecute and second method should call getvarient . how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 Controller has only one entry point by URL, so only execute method is called when you run it by URL.

You can call a different function from the execute method based on some condition or parameters. Following is the example.

```
public function execute()
{
    if(parameter1){
        $this->callFunctionOne();
    } elese {
        $this->callFunctionTwo();
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.